# Can I travel with just my Czech Republic ID card from Serbia to Budapest?

Tags: international-travel, paperwork, hungary, identity-cards

I have lost my passport here in Beograd. Can I travel just with my Czech ID card from Belgrade to Budapest?

Comment: Which country issued you this ID card?

Comment: @GeorgeY. title claims it's Czech Republic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can travel just with Czech ID card as Hungary is in European union and Czech republic has agreement with Serbia. Source: http://www.mzv.cz/jnp/cz/cestujeme/aktualni_doporuceni_a_varovani/srbsko_cestovani_na_obcansky_prukaz.mobi

Comment: It's not about being part of the European Union, it's about being part of the Schengen Treaty. (Which doesn't make a difference here, but still.)

Comment: Also the provided link is about *entering* Serbia.

Comment: @ytg All EU countries admit EU citizens with ID cards.  How is it not about being part of the EU?

Comment: @phoog I though non-schengen countries (like the UK) require a passport. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

EU citizens can enter **and exit** Serbia on a national ID Card, as stated by the [Serbian MFA](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime/81-consular-foreigners-to-serbia/11490-czech-republic-for-cons)

So if your foreigner registration is in order, you'll be fine.

Hungary is in the EU, so you have freedom of movement there and can enter with an ID card

Comment: What you linked is *also* about entering Serbia.

Answer (score 0):

We have two yes answers both of them with wrong reasoning, providing the wrong links: the OP is already in Serbia, the kind of documentation necessary to enter Serbia is irrelevant. ytg's comment is the winner: as Hungary and Czechia is part of the Schengen Treaty and the European union, you can use your national ID card to enter and travel within the Schengen area. 
[Travel documents for EU nationals](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm):

You need this paragraph to enter the Schengen zone at the Serbian-Hungarian border:

> When travelling to or from a non-Schengen country you must show a valid ID or passport.

And this one to go from Hungary to Czechia (possibly crossing SLovakia, another Schengen treaty member):

> If you are an EU national , you do not need to show your national ID card or passport when you are travelling from one border-free Schengen EU country to another.

Comment: It's not only about entering Hungary; it's also about exiting Serbia.